# Manga where the main character kills a demon lord but his brother takes credit and casts him out of the country

Tags: story-identification, manga

It's a manga where there are 4 heroes and the main character was the one wearing full plated armor. He killed a demon lord but his brother took credit for it. Then cast him out of the country.

Comment: This is quite a brief description, can you remember anything else about it? For example, when did you read it? What happened afterwards? How did they brother take credit? Who are the other heroes? etc. Anything else you remember will help people find this for you and you can [edit] your question to add in extra details.

Comment: I really cant remember anything else.

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like  *Yuusha no Gawari ni Maou Toubatsu Shitara Tegara wo Yokodoroi Saremashita* by Sekijou Hijiri and Kimizuka Shou, which I believe translates to  "False Hero Has No Place in this World" in English.

Description from online sources:

> As a member of the hero's party, Arga hid his identity and was on a
> journey to subjugate the Demon King with the hero. At last the party
> chased the demon king, and Arga brought him down. However, the hero
> insists that he was the one who killed the Demon King, and then
> charges Arga with an innocent sin and banishes him from the Imperial
> Palace. The warrior who devoted his life to the hero as a part of his
> corp would walk a new life in a strange country town.

Arga constantly wears a suit of plate armor in the manga, as I recall.

Comment: YES, YES, YES, THANK YOU! YES!